# How to monitor cancel state in the android Google login?

Tags: android

[image]

I refer to the following link to integrate Google login, this is the latest Google login.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start?hl=zh-cn

But this version can't cancel state monitoring, just like the picture above, if the user clicks on a dialog outside of the area, how can I listen to cancel the event?

The official offer code is as follows:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

But how to listen to cancel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my example:

```
    Log.d("result=", String.valueOf(result));
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        try {
            Log.i("Signin", acct.getDisplayName());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error retrieving some account information");
        }
    } else {
        Status status = result.getStatus();
        int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();
        Log.d("StatusCode", String.valueOf(statusCode));
        if (statusCode == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {

        }
        else if (statusCode == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_FAILED) {

        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

You can retrieve a statuscode with `result.getStatus();`
Now you can compare the statusCode in the else part with `GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED`

Comment: thanks,but why SIGN_IN_CANCELLED value is 12501, when I'm wrong configuration sign - in Google, returns the error code is 12501.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = null;
    try {
        account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        if (e.getStatusCode() != GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            // cancelled
        } else {
            // error
        }
    }
    if (account != null) {
        // ok
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, should be `e.getStatusCode() == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED` for cancelled case

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check below link to know how to Sign In and Sign Out. Also get user information

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/src/android/GooglePlus.java

Comment: thanks,but this is old version of google sign-in ,Please check my above connection, this is Google's latest login, but this version how to cancel state monitoring, when the selection box pops up Google account, I have no choice, but to click on the dialog box outside, cancel the login?

Comment: Please, Now you can check above updated link... this is you want